# Is there a way to layer colors and SVG to make a background

Tags: css, background, background-image, background-color

Is it possible to have a background color, then have a SVG file in front of that then another layer with opacity in front of that? Im trying to do a cool effect for the background of a website. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is possible, but please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could play around with `z-index` for that.
This should work, a live example is at https://codepen.io/tixpro/pen/VwadJxo

```
<body class='main'>
  Hello
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Yin_yang.svg" />
  <div class='overlay'></div>
</body>

<style>
  body{
   background-color:#424242;
   background-size: 'cover'
}
 
/*overlay styling, source: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_overlay.asp */
.overlay{
  position: fixed; /* Sit on top of the page content */
  width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
  height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(4,0,0,0.5); /* Black background with opacity */
  z-index: 2;
}
</style>
```